# how to set POST or GET value to filter in joomla 3.x custom component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

How to assign HTTP request (GET or POST) value to the filter for the custom component list view

I have create the custom component which maintain product details and stock details, whenever the stock become low it'll send email to admin, in that i have pass the value for product and product category value in URL link using query string. when the admin click link from the email,it will go to the stock page and show the product details from the list of product.

The problem i was facing is, it not showing result for **url query string value** when click the mail link, it only showing previous **session state** value.

Note:
     Otherwise filter working well in back-end and front-end,and showing the result properly.

am using below code in **edit.php**.

```
    $jInput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

      // From GET
     $qid = $jInput->get->get( 'qid', 0, 'INT' );
     $qcatid = $jInput->get->get( 'qcatid', 0, 'INT' );

     if(!empty($qid)){
     //$proname="id:".$qid;
     $proname =$model->getArticleDetails('name',$qid);

     $this->state->set('filter.search',$proname);
     if(!empty($qcatid))
     $this->state->set('filter.productcat',$qcatid); ?>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     document.id('filter_search').value='<?php echo $proname; ?>';
     document.id('productcatselect').value='<?php echo $qcatid; ?>';
     document.forms["adminForm"].submit();
     }
     </script>

    <?php } ?>
```

In the model file **constructor**

```
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    if (empty($config['filter_fields'])) {
        $config['filter_fields'] = array(
            'product', 'a.fk_product_code',
            'productcat', 'a.fk_productcat',
        );
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

**in populateState function**

```
    //Filtering productname
    $search =trim($this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search', '', 'string'));
    $this->setState('filter.search', $search);

    //Filtering productcat
    $this->setState('filter.productcat', $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.productcat', 'filter_productcat', ''));
```

Note:
      Product name using textbox filter, Product category using selectListbox filter.

**Query string url is**

```
'<a target="_blank" href="index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=my_view&qid=product_id&qcatid=product_id">link</a>'
```

Found the solution, Instead of above link. Pass the email link like below

```
<a target="_blank" href="index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=my_view&filter_search=product_name&filter_productcat=product_id">link</a>
```

Note:
  **filter_search**,**filter_productcat** are filter name, Refer from  **populateState function**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for set HTTP request (GET or POST) value to search filter by using **getUserStateFromRequest** by refer [docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables)

It will help some one who face same Problem, Here is the code.

```
/**
 * Gets the value of a user state variable and sets it in the session
 *
 * This is the same as the method in JApplication except that this also can optionally
 * force you back to the first page when a filter has changed
 *
 * @param   string   $key        The key of the user state variable.
 * @param   string   $request    The name of the variable passed in a request.
 * @param   string   $default    The default value for the variable if not found. Optional.
 * @param   string   $type       Filter for the variable, for valid values see {@link JFilterInput::clean()}. Optional.
 * @param   boolean  $resetPage  If true, the limitstart in request is set to zero
 *
 * @return  The request user state.
 *
 * @since   12.2
 */
public function getUserStateFromRequest($key, $request, $default = null, $type = 'none', $resetPage = true);
```

Refer from the above syntax $request indicate **HTTP request (GET or POST) value**

The custom component model file modle **populateState** have below code

```
    $search =trim($this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search', '', 'string'));
    $this->setState('filter.search', $search);
    //Filtering productcat
    $this->setState('filter.productcat', $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.productcat', 'filter_productcat', ''));
```

so in the email url i pass query string like

```
 '<a target="_blank" href="index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=my_view&filter_search=product_name&filter_productcat=product_id">link</a>';
```

**Note: “getUserStateFromRequest” method will update the user state variable, if a HTTP request (GET or POST) contains the “filter_productcat”**

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean, but if you don't mind your filter parameters in arrays in POST & GET, e.g. `?filter[productcat]=10`, then in  your list model you almost have to do nothing since all filters will then be populated automatically (and remembered for users).

**Constructor:**

```
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    //Allow filtering (en ordering)
    $config['filter_fields']=array('search','productcat');

    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

**getListQuery:**

```
protected function getListQuery()
{       
    ...//some code

    $search     = $this->getState('filter.search');
    $productcat = $this->getState('filter.productcat');

    ...//Some query code

    // Filter search
    if (!empty($productcat)) {
        $query->where('productcat='.$productcat);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

**Links or forms**: Make sure to use arrays:

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_custom&filter[productcat]=8');?>">
//or
<input ... name="filter[productcat]" ...>
```

Comment: Thank You for the Answer :).I have updated my post and also found solution.Previously the filter working fine in back-end and front-end, only thing it doesn't responding the query string value form email link. am using *getUserStateFromRequest* filter name for value holder and passed it in query string url,all working fine now..